# Trying to extract a leaf field from Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have an object in elasticsearch which resembles something like this:

```
{
"text": "something something something",
"entities": { "hashtags":["test","test123"]}
}
```

The problem is that not each document has the entities attribute set. So I want to write a query which:

- must contain a keyword in the `text` field
- must have the `entities` field
- extracts the `entities.hashtag` field

I'm trying to extract a leaf field using following query, the problem is  I still get documents which don't have an `entities` field.

For the second part of the question, I was wondering: How do I only extract the `entities.hashtags` field? I tried something like  `"fields": ["entities.hashtags"]` but it didn't work.

```
{
    "size": 2000,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {

                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "term": {
                            "text": "something"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "missing": {
                            "field": "entities",
                            "existence": true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you want, if I'm understanding you correctly. A `"term"` filter on the `"text"` field and an [`"exists"` filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-filter.html) on the `"entities"` field filters the docs, and a [`"terms"` aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on `"entities.hashtags"` extracts the values. I'll just post the full example I used:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   }
}

PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
   "text": "something something something",
   "entities": { "hashtags": ["test","test123"] }
}

PUT /test_index/doc/2
{
   "text": "another doc",
   "entities": { "hashtags": ["testagain","testagain123"] }
}

PUT /test_index/doc/3
{
   "text": "doc with no entities"
}

POST /test_index/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  { "term": {  "text": "something" } },
                  { "exists": { "field": "entities" } }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "hashtags": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "entities.hashtags"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 35,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "hashtags": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "test",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "test123",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```